# Proof that covariant and contravariant indices are equivalent for Cartesian tensors.

Tags: proof-writing, tensors

From [1], we have a proposition.

> **Proposition** While the distinction between covariant and contravariant indices must be made for general tensors, the two are equivalent for tensors in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, and such tensors are known as Cartesian tensors.

**Questions**

1. How can we formulate a proof of this proposition?
2. Can you offer a worked example that elucidates the proposition?

**Bibliography**

[1] https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tensor.html

Comment: Hint: the metric is $\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: I welcome a clearer definition...